# osCommerce with Apache HTTP server 2.2

Tags: php, apache, oscommerce

> Copy the oscommerce directory to your web server htdocs directory and open the location with >your browser. Setup will automatically
>   launch and guide you through the installation and configuration of
>   your new online store.

I copied the said folder into htdocs, in my browser I go to localhost which displays the index.html in the htdocs folder already (just says "it works!"). I do not see the setup launch?

I installed PHP 5, but not sure if I done it right, I just used the MSI installer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete the index.html in that folder and you've done. This answer presume that all the configuration are all right.

Comment: I now just get the directory list.

Comment: Have you a index.php file in that folder (you must have)? If you have and apache does not load it automatically, you have an apache configuration problem(s).

Comment: C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\oscommerce\index.php

Comment: Well. As I said in my answer, to achieve your goal, you had to delete the index.html (so the answer is right). That said, it has not been working because you have some apache configuration problem(s).

Comment: I figured I haven't configured this file: httpd.conf - but i cannot find this dll php5apache2_2.dll.

Comment: I found the .dll by downloading the thread safe PHP .zip, followed this tutorial to set up the conf file... still doesn't work right.

Comment: If you don't know how to setup a local server, i suggest you to install WAMP or LAMP (depending on what operating system you are running).